# Creating a hash inside an array that contains hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

Let me preface this by saying I am just starting to learn ruby...

I have any array that is made of hashes, and arrays nested within each other. It looks like this:

```
 people =
[
  {
    "John Doe" => {
      "phone" => "555-555-555",
      "company" => "Company name",
      "children" => [
        "John",
        "Jane",
        "Annamarie"
      ]
    },
    "Jane Smith" => {
      "phone" => "555-555-5555",
      "company" => "company name",
      "children" => [
        "Steven"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

How would I go about adding a new hash where the name of the person acts as a key, and the new hash is the value? E.g. I want to add "spouse" so the hash would look like this:

```
people =
[
  {
    "John Doe" => {
      "phone" => "555-555-555",
      "company" => "Company name",
      "children" => [
        "John",
        "Jane",
        "Annamarie"
      ],
      "spouse" => "Jane Doe"
    },
    "Jane Smith" => {
      "phone" => "555-555-5555",
      "company" => "company name",
      "children" => [
        "Steven"
      ],
      "spouse" => "John Smith"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Why do you need the topmost array around your hash with person=>their_data ?

Comment: @Vasfed This was part of an exercise, and it was given to me this way. The original question was about creating a hash at the people level, but I wanted to figure out how to go one layer deeper, which I haven't been able to do. Long story short, this was given to me, and is purely hypothetical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `select` to get the hash with "John Doe" as the key...

```
    search_user = "John Doe"
    person = people.select{|p| p.has_key?(search_user)}.first
    person[search_user]['spouse'] = "Jane Doe" if person
```

The reason for `if person` on the last line is to handle the case that no "John Doe" was found.

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your reply. However, I am trying to create the a new hash inside of the hash where John Doe is the key. Or am I misunderstanding your code?

Comment: My code has a new hash-key/data within the hash "John Doe"... the results of my code will exactly match your "I want it to look like this" code.  If your description / example of what you wanted is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm still very new to this. I appreciate you taking the time to answer this.